# Fetch php response using angularjs

Tags: php, angularjs, post

I'm using angularjs for my app and php to fetch data from server...
The php file gets all the needed variables but when i'm trying to see the answer using angular I only get [object Object], [object Object] and so on...
Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
Angular code:
  app.controller('FormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
  $scope.submit = function() {

    var data = {
        'days': $scope.days,
        'age_18': $scope.age_18,
        'age_13_17': $scope.age_13_17,
        'age_8_12': $scope.age_8_12,
        'age_3_7': $scope.age_3_7,
        'water': true,
        'outside': true
    }

    $http.post('php/get_data.php', data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert(data);
    })

  }
 }])
```

Php Code:

```
  <?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "nathan", "nathan", "nathan");

  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);

  $age_18 = $request->age_18;
  $age_13_17 = $request->age_13_17;
  $age_8_12 = $request->age_8_12;
  $age_3_7 = $request->age_3_7;
  $days = $request->days;
  $water = $request->water;
  $outside = $request->outside;

  $result = $conn->query("SELECT id, modal_name, name,('$age_18'*18_rating + '$age_13_17'*13_17_rating
            + '$age_8_12'*8_12_rating + '$age_3_7'*3_7_rating) as total
            FROM parks
            WHERE (water_park LIKE '$water' OR water_park LIKE 0)
                   and (outside_orlando LIKE '$outside' OR outside_orlando LIKE 0)
            ORDER BY total DESC");

  $outp = "[";
  while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
      $outp .= '{"name":"'        . $rs["name"]       . '",';
      $outp .= '"modal_name":"'   . $rs["modal_name"] . '",';
      $outp .= '"id":"'           . $rs["id"]         . '"}'; 
}
$outp .="]";

$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output you get is an array of objects.

Try the following :

```
$http.post('php/get_data.php', data)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
            alert(data[j].name);
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this and tell me if it is working for you:

```
$http.post('php/get_data.php', JSON.stringify(data))
   .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      alert(data);
})
```